# Shorthand for single item to collection c#

Tags: c#

I have a lot of code that takes on the following pattern

```
void Add(int foo)
{
 $my question
}

void Add(List<int> bar)
{
//do stuff
}
```

I was wondering (other than writing an extension method) if there was something 'shorter than writing:

`Add(new List<int>(new int[]{foo}));`

everytime I wanted to call the second method. Hoping to find a gem ive missed in the .net library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can modify the second method, it **might** be better if it was

```
void Add(params int[] bar)
{
}
```

Then you can call it like `Add(foo, foo2, foo3)` or `Add(myList.ToArray())`

Have a look at the [params keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using C# 3 or higher, you can use a [*collection initializer*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
Add(new List<int> { foo });
```

This is equivalent to:

```
List<int> tmp = new List<int>();
tmp.Add(foo);
Add(tmp);
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it is sufficiently shorter enough, but this will work as well:

```
Add(new List<int> { foo });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a collection initializer directly on the List:

```
Add(new List<int> { foo });
```

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use `IEnumerable` for sequence arguments and `new []` syntax to pass an implicitly typed array:

```
public void Add (IEnumerable<int> bar)
{
}

// accepts:
Add (new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 });
Add (Enumerable.Range (1, 10));
Add (new [] { 1 });
```

As a variant, you may want to define an “amplifying” extension method:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Amplify (T item)
{
    yield return item;
}

Add (1.Amplify ())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor code something similar to the follow:

```
void Add(int bar)
{
    //Code for single element
}
void Add(List<int> foo)
{
    foreach(int i in foo)
    {
        Add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not always the case. Sometimes you want to filter elements, aggregate over them, whatever. LINQ fits so much better than `if` guards, if such functionality is needed.